# Interfering keys in Processing 2

Tags: processing, draw

I'm trying to activate different visuals by pressing different keys. For example, when I press "z" or "Z", an ellipse on a specific position flows down, leaving a trace behind. If I wait for it to reach the canvas border, there's no problem but when I press "0" which activates another ellipse on another position to do the same thing, the ellipse of "z"/"Z" stops flowing. It also happens when I press the same key before the ellipse reaches canvas border. How can I fix this? When I started to code this, I didn't know classes and objects, then I learned and tried to solve it by using creating an object but it got worse, ellipses didn't work at all. I want the first ellipse to continue until the border even if I press another key while it's on its way.

Another thing is I wanted them to fade out after a short time, so I drew semi-transparent rectangles on canvas which seems very primitive to me. Would you suggest a different way? This is less important but it would be better to have them completely fade over time rather than leaving a slight trace.

Here's my code, I cleaned irrelevant parts to make it look more understandable:

```
void setup() {
  size(640, 500);
  background(bgRenk);
  frameRate(60);
  colorMode(HSB);
  noStroke();
}

int bgRenk = #e7e7e7;
int C3Yer;
int C3Y;
int Fd6Yer;
int Fd6Y;

void draw() {

  // This part probably sucks because it's a primitive solution to make ellipses fade out by putting semi-transparent rectangles on the canvas.

  fill(bgRenk, 10);
  rect(0, 0, 640, 500);

  // I basically map x and y positions to hue and opacity.

  float C3Renk= map(C3Yer, 0, width, 0, 255);
  float C3Opak = map(C3Y, height, 0, 0, 200);

  // When z/Z is pressed, an ellipse appears and goes down, leaving trace behind.   
  if (key == 'z' || key == 'Z') {
    C3Yer = 10;
    fill(C3Renk, 255, 255, C3Opak);
    ellipse(C3Yer, C3Y, 20, 20);
    C3Y += 20;
  }


  if (key == '0') {

    // Same mapping and ellipse thing.

    float Fd6Renk= map(Fd6Yer, 0, width, 0, 255);
    float Fd6Opak = map(Fd6Y, height, 0, 0, 200);
    Fd6Yer = 630;
    fill(Fd6Renk, 255, 255, Fd6Opak);
    ellipse(Fd6Yer, Fd6Y, 20, 20);
    Fd6Y += 20;
  }
}

void keyPressed() {


  if (key == 'z' || key == 'Z') {

    // When z/Z is pressed, y position of those ellipses are reset.


    C3Y = 10;
  }


  if (key == '0') {

    // Same reset thing.      

    Fd6Y = 10;
  }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with creating new ellipse while other is still flowing is with variable `key` which always contains the value of the most recent key used (for more [see](https://processing.org/reference/key.html)). So when you press **any** key after "z" your ellipse will stop being drawn. 
You can avoid this using global variables indicating which ellipses should be drawn.

But I would suggest using creating objects that will have defined state (position, color, opacity) and will be stored inside array or list. It will also help you with fading so find a time and read more about classes and [objects](https://processing.org/tutorials/objects/). On processing site you can find nice [tutorials](https://processing.org/tutorials/) like this [one](https://processing.org/tutorials/arrays/)

But because you sad you already tried creating objects and i don't works I will give you few tips and basic example of such a class:

```java
class Ball {
  float x, y;       // position of ball
  color col = 10;   // color of ball
  int opac = 255;   // opacity of ball

  Ball(float _x, float _y) {
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
  }

  void move() {    
    y += 20;
    opac -= 10;
  }

  void display() {        
    fill(col, 255, 255, opac);
    ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
  }
}
```

Then you can create new `ball` objects:

```java
void mousePressed() {
  //this will create new ball on mouse position
  balls.add( new Ball(mouseX, mouseY) );
}
```

and store them into `ArrayList` like this:

```java
ArrayList<Ball> balls = new ArrayList();
```

Last thing that you need to do is `display` and `move` all balls within `draw` method.

```java
for (Ball b : balls) // for each ball in list
{
  b.display(); // first display ball
  b.move();    // move and change opacity
}
```

This is very basic example and should be improved but I hope it will help you with understanding of classes.

Comment: Thank you very much. My class was very similar with yours but I didn't have "void move()" part which could be the problem, I tried to move it with a different and unsuccessful approach. Also, I was using "Ball.display()" thing, rather than "balls.add( new Ball(mouseX, mouseY) )" under void keyPressed(). I will try this as soon as possible, thank you again.